# Input returning empty string after submitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the values and console.log what that user submitted. My log message after submit returns an empty string.
Styled components used so all components are divs except Post (form), Input (input) and Button (button)

```
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState("");

  const textHandler = () => event =>{
    setEnteredText(event.target.value);
  };
  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const textData = {
      text: enteredText,
    };
    console.log(textData);
  };
  return (
    <Post onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <TopPost>
        <ProfilePicture></ProfilePicture>
        <Input
          placeholder="What's happening?"
          required
          onChange={textHandler}
        />
      </TopPost>
      <BottomPost>
        <Button type="submit">Post</Button>
      </BottomPost>
    </Post>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because you have additional parentheses in the `textHandler` function here they shouldn't be.

**You wrote:**

```js
const textHandler = () => event =>{
   setEnteredText(event.target.value);
};
```

**While it should be:**

```js
const textHandler = event => {
   setEnteredText(event.target.value);
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're problem actually is. Not to mention you have custom component there for the input / form / etc.. So there is no way for me to be sure. But [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-pond-gdhs4p?file=/src/App.js) is a simple example that works.

Comment: If i change the extra parenthesis my page reloads after every keyboard press. I tried adding event.preventDefault() but it's not working

Comment: I should've added but I'm using styled components so all "custom" components are just divs with styling (except Post that is a form and Input which is an input)

Comment: If you can provide an exact example in codesandbox I could actually check and might be able to help, but as mentioned, if [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-pond-gdhs4p?file=/src/App.js) works, then I don't see a reason for your code not to work.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-voice-j2tbuh?file=/src/App.js try now sorry

Comment: You have nested component here, which we don't do. Once I put the styled components outside of `CreatePost` everything works just fine. P.S. there are console errors about it, so also worth checking it out when something doesn't work.

Comment: I was kinda procrastinating solving that warning because i thought it wouldn't change the functionality part. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The function you need is that accepts `event` and then sets state, but
You have passed funtcion that returns that function instead of setting state.

You have written:

```
onChange={textHandler}
```

Insetad you have to run that function to get `event` accepted function.

##### Solution 1:

```
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState("");

  const textHandler = () => event =>{
    setEnteredText(event.target.value);
  };
  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const textData = {
      text: enteredText,
    };
    console.log(textData);
  };
  return (
    <Post onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <TopPost>
        <ProfilePicture></ProfilePicture>
        <Input
          placeholder="What's happening?"
          required
          onChange={textHandler()} // Here you have to run this function instead just passing
        />
      </TopPost>
      <BottomPost>
        <Button type="submit">Post</Button>
      </BottomPost>
    </Post>
  );
```

##### Solution 2 (Recomended, since I can't see the need of returninng function)

```
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState("");

  // Just use event handler funtion, no need to return nested function
  const textHandler = event => {
    setEnteredText(event.target.value);
  };
  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const textData = {
      text: enteredText,
    };
    console.log(textData);
  };
  return (
    <Post onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <TopPost>
        <ProfilePicture></ProfilePicture>
        <Input
          placeholder="What's happening?"
          required
          onChange={textHandler}
        />
      </TopPost>
      <BottomPost>
        <Button type="submit">Post</Button>
      </BottomPost>
    </Post>
  );
```

Comment: When I try = event => my page automatically refreshes every time I type. I also tried adding event.preventDefault() but it's not working

Comment: It shouldn't. Show us full code, may be there's another problem

Comment: That link is just empty codesandbox link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-voice-j2tbuh?file=/src/App.js Didn't save, sorry

Comment: You have styled components inside function. When state changes function re-runs and refreshes all components, that's why input is loosing focus, becaus it has got new ref.
Just place styled components outside function. https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-field-6i7nz3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: If this answer helped you to solve issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: It was already answered before. More than once actually..

Answer (score 1):

Try this! and figure out your mistake still can't find it then let me know. styled-component should be outside you `Post component like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Post = styled.form`
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0vh 2vw;
  border-radius: 6px;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
const TopPost = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 50%;
  align-items: center;
`;
const ProfilePicture = styled.div`
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
`;
const Input = styled.input`
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2vh 1vw;
  border: transparent;
  background-color: #f0f2f4;
  font-weight: 500;
`;
const BottomPost = styled.div`
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
`;
const Button = styled.button`
  margin-right: 2vw;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.8vw 2.5vw;
  background-color: #377dff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export default function CreatePost() {
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState('');

  // Just use event handler funtion, no need to return nested function
  const textHandler = event => {
    setEnteredText(event.target.value);
  };
  const submitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const textData = {
      text: enteredText,
    };
    console.log(textData);
  };
  return (
    <Post onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <TopPost>
        <ProfilePicture></ProfilePicture>
        <Input placeholder="What's happening?" required onChange={textHandler} />
      </TopPost>
      <BottomPost>
        <Button type='submit'>Post</Button>
      </BottomPost>
    </Post>
  );
}
```

Comment: When i change = event => my page reloads on every type. I tried adding event.preventDefault() but it's not working.

Comment: Can you show what inside `Post` component and `Input` component

Comment: It's just styled components. It's a form and input with styling

Comment: nope there is something that triggering page reload

Comment: did input component also contain form inside ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-voice-j2tbuh?file=/src/App.js Nothing is coming from outside

Comment: styled-component should be outside fixed your issue check out